# Is there a type restricted Maybe style "Nothing"?

Tags: haskell, gadt

Consider the following code:

```
data T b where
  T :: Maybe (a -> b) -> a -> T b

g (T (Just f) x) = f x
g (T Nothing x) = x
```

this does not compile, we get an error on the `Nothing` definition of `g`. The reason of this is because `Nothing` does not prevent the internal type `a` from being different to the externally visible type `b`.

Now consider this alternative approach:

```
data Maybe' b a where
  Just' :: a -> Maybe' b a
  Nothing' :: Maybe' b b

data T' b where
  T' :: Maybe' (a -> a) (a -> b) -> a -> T' b

g' (T' (Just' f) x) = f x
g' (T' Nothing' x) = x
```

This compiles without issue.

Here's another fun example of what this allows:

```
dotMaybe :: 
  Maybe' (dummy1 -> dummy1) (b -> c) -> 
  Maybe' (dummy2 -> dummy2) (a -> b) -> 
  Maybe' (dummy2 -> dummy2) (a -> c)
dotMaybe (Just' f) (Just' g) = Just' (f . g)
dotMaybe (Just' f) Nothing' = Just' f
dotMaybe Nothing' (Just' g) = Just' g
dotMaybe Nothing' Nothing' = Nothing'
```

Is there a package already available on Hackage that allows for the sort of functionality demonstrated in `Maybe'`, or should I package something up? I just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could use `T :: Either (a -> b) (Dict (a ~ b)) -> a -> T b`  (where [`Dict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9.1/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Dict) is from `constraints` package)

Comment: I assume `Either (Dict (a ~ b)) (a -> b)` would be a better approach, replacing `Just` with `Right` and `Nothing` with `Left Dict`?

Comment: sure?  You get `Either`'s various instances in one parameter versus the other, but it's an aesthetic issue.  I usually don't use `Either`'s single-parameter instances anyway, preferring the [`ArrowChoice`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowChoice) combinators, which are more symmetrical.

Comment: Also consider `Either (a -> b) (a :~: b)`, using `Data.Type.Equality.(:~:)`